# Javascript : Allow the user to write to session when submitting a form but without reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

As per requirement, I want to allow the user to write to session when submitting a form but without reloading the page, this is what i have done so far:

Javascript function:

```
$(function() {
$("#body").submit(function(){
var name = $("#player_name").val();
var dataString = 'player_name='+ name
alert (dataString);return false; 
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "session_update.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(){
        $('#body').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
        $('#message').html("<h2>Logged in!</h2>");
      });
   }
});
   return false;
});
```

My form im trying to submit:

```
    <div class="body">
<div class="home" id="home" style="width:100%">
    <form action="" name="login">
    USERNAME: <input type="text" id="player_name" name="player_name"/>
          <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
         </form>
<? echo "value=". $_SESSION['player_name'];?>
</div>
```

the php file its sending the data to:

```
<?php
start_session();
$_SESSION['player_name']= $_POST["player_name"];
?>
```

any advice your be greatly appreciated, fairly new to this side of coding so it could be something obvious thats causing it but i just cant see it.

For more information let me know.

**UPDATE**

Console showing
?player_name=User&send:75

Comment: what is currect result ? what is reason for use `data: dataString` instead of `data: {player_name: name}` ?

Comment: nothing is happening when i press the submit button, its like its not even running the function

Comment: UPDATE:)
Console showing when clicking submit:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) /?player_name=User:39
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `session_start();` not `start_session()`

Always ensure that you test your PHP scripts manually, not just pointing to the page with ajax. Go to it and make sure it works. :-)

If you tested this (assuming error_reporting is on), you will have received an error stating that you are trying to call an undefined function.

**UPDATE**

In addition to the `session_start()` issue, you have may other problems in your code.

First step is to debug using either `console.log('hello');` or `alert('hello')`. Bind these actions to the form submit event and this will tell you whether or not the submit function is being called.

Once you have done this then you can continue to debug the rest :-)

**UPDATE 2**

From looking at your jQuery, it would appear that you are attaching the `submit` event to the wrong element in the DOM. You need to attach it to the form, not a div. Like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        var name = $("#player_name").val();
        var dataString = 'player_name='+ name
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "session_update.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(){
            $('#body').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
            $('#message').html("<h2>Logged in!</h2>");
          });
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="home" id="home" style="width:100%">
        <form id="form" action="" name="login">
            USERNAME:<input type="text" id="player_name" name="player_name"/><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
        </form>
        <? echo "value=". $_SESSION['player_name'];?>
    </div>
```

***TIP: Use CSS to space elements, don't use `br` tags. Just my opinion :-)***

Comment: hi, i changed this but im still not getting a result from it?

Comment: @Scott Okay, first issue sorted. I'll look into it more :-)

Comment: @Scott First thing to do is debug your code, you need to check the console to ensure the ajax is being called and there are no errors.

Comment: where would i find the console? im using 000webhost and cant seem to find it, i have put an alert in the .php file but its not being called, the alert in the js script is also not being called

Comment: @Scott Don't put an `alert` in the PHP file, `alert` is a javascript function :-) The console is in your browser, what browser are you using?

Comment: ahh right, i changed that to console and im using chrome, i also changed the jquery like in update 2 and still no change

Comment: Right, press F12. This will fire up the developer tools. First thing to look at is the console, so click on the console tab on the right. Paste any errors displayed there into your question under a heading UPDATE :-)

Comment: @Scott See what happens when you submit with an empty field

Comment: i tried it with an empty field and nothing is showing in console, tried with data and again nothing in console

Comment: @Scott Firstly, make sure you are refreshing the page to empty the console. If there are any things shown when the page loads, paste them into your question (not the comments section). Just click edit below the question

Answer (score 1):

```
also remove return false from the middle of your code


$(function() {
$("#body").submit(function(){
var name = $("#player_name").val();

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "session_update.php",
      data: {player_name:name},
      success: function(){
        $('#body').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
        $('#message').html("<h2>Logged in!</h2>");
      });
   }
});
   return false;
});
```

Comment: fixed this along with the issue below and still no change

Answer (score 1):

You attaching event to incorrect element.

In js change

`$("#body").submit(function(){`

to

`$("#myform").submit(function(){`

in html

`<form action="" name="login">`

to

`<form id='myform' action="" name="login">`

You also have several syntax errors, fixed here:

```
$(function() {
$("#myform").submit(function(){
var name = $("#player_name").val();
var dataString = 'player_name='+ name;
alert (dataString);
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "session_update.php",
      data: {player_name: name},
      success: function(){
        $('body').append("<div id='message'></div>");  
        $('#message').html("<h2>Logged in!</h2>");
      }//here was )
   });
     return false;
});//  |
  //   \/return was here
});​
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/NnERs/)

**main tip - use development console (press F12) to debug your code**

Comment: Hi, i have changed these and still same result

Comment: Hi, have tried the updated code and still no luck, had a look at the working example and its throwing the following in console:

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/contentScript1.js:62Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined

can you shed any light on these?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to submit the form:

1. Change the type="submit" of the `submit_btn` into a type="button".
2. Bind the the AJAX call of the `session_update.php` page to the `submit_btn` click event.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this. I think the problem is with your click event.

```
$(function() {

    $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
    var name = $("#player_name").val();
    var dataString = 'player_name='+ name
    alert (dataString);return false; 
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "session_update.php",
              data: dataString,
              success: function(){
                $('#body').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
                $('#message').html("<h2>Logged in!</h2>");
              });
           }
    });

});
```

Comment: hi, this did not work either, it didnt seem to submit anything